# When do we need to separate areas while calculating definite integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

Many times when the function has range $f(x) \lt 0$ and also $f(x) > 0$ and we want to calculate an area of the function we need to separate the area in two parts. Thus, we will calculate the whole area as:
$$S = \big{\lvert} S_1\big\rvert +\big\lvert S_2\big\rvert$$

This is because the definite integral of $S_1$ or the one of $S_2$ could be negative.

However, in many cases we don't. For example, with $$f(x) = x + \sin^2x$$

[image]

Here in this image we don't need to separate the areas for calculating for example the area between $-\pi\le x \le \pi$. But why?

Could you give examples where we need to separate the areas and sum them up with absolute values, and examples where we don't need.

Comment: What do you mean "here" we don't? WolframAlpha does not mention areas anywhere ...

Comment: Do you know odd,even functions we split up areas if by doing so we get even and odd function which would give resultant area as $0$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I mean *here* by the image of the function.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I edited the question.

Comment: Basically you don't need any extra tinkering with the function if you can just compute a primitive.

Comment: @CaptainLama What do you mean by *compute a primitive*?

Comment: Well, it's not too hard to see that $f = g'$ with $g(x) = \frac{1}{2} (x+x^2-\cos(x) \sin(x))$ (unless I made a mistake, but in any case it's computable), so $\int_a^b f = g(b)-g(a)$ and you don't have to make any geometric reasoning.